# python issue adds a new label

Tags: python, tkinter

take a look at this code
well it happens to just add another label for no reason

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
clicks = 1
def click_count():

    global clicks

    # making the label that shows how many idk you have

    label = Label(frame, text="you have " + str(clicks), font=(('Courrier'), 32))
    label.pack()
    clicks += 1
    label.pack()




#generating the window
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')


#making the expandable frame
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(expand=YES)

#making the button
button = Button(frame, text= "click", font=(('Courrier'), 32), command=click_count)
button.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

and then i tried this
and i also tried to remove the label.pack at the end
but it still does the same thing which is adding another label

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
clicks = 1
def click_count():

    global clicks

    # making the label that shows how many idk you have

    label = Label(frame, text="you have " + str(clicks), font=(('Courrier'), 32))
    label.pack()
    label.destroy()
    clicks += 1
    label.pack()




#generating the window
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')


#making the expandable frame
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(expand=YES)

#making the button
button = Button(frame, text= "click", font=(('Courrier'), 32), command=click_count)
button.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

i was expecting it to add a nmber to the label but it just shows another label

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

It does not add a Label for no reason. It adds the label because that's what your function tells it to do. Each time you click the button, the function is executed that creates and packs a new Label.

What you should do is create the label at the onset and link it to a variable. Then, you can change the value of this variable in the function.

Also, you don't have to import tkinter twice and it's sensible to update the clicker first and then display the result instead of showing the last value it had. Your approach works in such a small program but the value of `clicks` will always be one higher than displayed. So, you may get into problems when you use the value.

```
from tkinter import *

def click_count():
    global clicks
    clicks += 1
    click_counter.set("you have " + str(clicks))

#Initiate root
root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

#Set initial values for click counter
clicks = 0
click_counter = StringVar()
click_counter.set("you have 0")

#making the expandable frame
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(expand=YES)

# making the label that shows how many idk you have
label = Label(frame, textvariable=click_counter, font=(('Courrier'), 32)) ## The label gets updated, whenever the value of click_counter changes.
label.pack()

#making the button
button = Button(frame, text= "click", font=(('Courrier'), 32), command=click_count)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```